# RegEx for the <li></li> tags

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, visual-studio-2008

i am working on the C# WinForm application. In that application, i have snippet like this:

```
<ul>
<li>abc
<li>bbc
<li>xyz
<li>pqr </li></li></li></li>     
</ul>
```

but, i want to get output like..

```
<ul>
<li>abc</li>
<li>bbc</li>
<li>xyz</li>
<li>pqr</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any method using which this thing can be done?

Can anybody suggest me any RegEx for this problem?

Thanks. Regards.

Comment: How dows regular expressions solve this? What are you doing?

Comment: don't understand why minuses. normal question

Comment: Is there any other method to solve it ? i m curious

Comment: I'd strip all the tags and then split on Environment.NewLine into an array. Use that to add tags to make right.

Comment: Wont work if Newline is not there ? i think it should be Dynamic !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Sangram No, that's true, but given the messy nature of HTML, there are other ways, like replacing all tags with \n and then take it from there. It's not pretty and I like Tim Pietzcker's solution a lot better, despite that it may break. But that's regex for you.

Comment: Where is the input from and why do you need to transform it? Just fyi, '<ul><li>abc <li>bbc <li>xyz </ul>' is perfectly valid HTML, as the closing tags are optional. You then have a bunch of closing tags which don't actually close anything and are ignored by most lenient parsers.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple without using any fancy regex

Try below, you can implement your own code

```
   1. first Remove all </li>'s from the snippet
          line.replace("</li>","")
   2. Read each line starts with <li>
          if (line.startswith("<li">)
   3. and append the </li> at the end
          line+ ="</li>"
   4. combine all the line
           resString += line;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on your specific example, but may well break on other input (for example, if `<li>` tags were to span linebreaks), so if it's not producing the desired results, please edit your question with more details.

```
cleanString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "(?:</li>)+", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
resultString = Regex.Replace(cleanString, "<li>(.*)", "<li>$1</li>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: i run this code but there is some problem. last </li> is append after </ul> but it is append before </li>.

Comment: It works correctly on your example. If the `<ul>` is on the same line as the `</li>`, though, then it will not work correctly. Please post the exact contents you're working with (edit your question to do so). If you provide incomplete or unrealistic test data, you will get a solution that's incomplete, too.

Comment: I'm curious, if you time this, how fast is it?

Answer (score 1):

public string AddLiandOl(string xhtml)
        {

```
            xhtml = xhtml.Replace("</li>", string.Empty);
            xhtml = xhtml.Replace("<li>", "</li><li>");
            xhtml = xhtml.Replace("</ol>", "</li></ol>");
            xhtml = xhtml.Replace("</ul>", "</li></ul>");
            Regex replaceul = new Regex("<ul>(.+?)</li>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            xhtml = replaceul.Replace(xhtml,"<ul>");
            Regex replaceol = new Regex("<ol>(.+?)</li>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            xhtml = replaceol.Replace(xhtml, "<ol>");

        return xhtml;

    }
```

Try this i have tested it. it works...It hardly takes 30 seconds to replace all tags..

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("<ul>\n");
foreach (i in Regex.Matches(snippet, "<li>\\w*"))
{
    output.Append(i.Value).Append("</li>\n");
}
output.Append("\n</ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest solution to your problem, but it's crazy fast. Regex's are slow compared to straight string methods.

My string method compared to Tim Pietzcker's two Regex.Replace's. (Sorry Tim, I had to pick on someone, and you have the upvote :)  )

this is with 10,000 reps. numbers are number of elapsed ticks:

regex replace:
avg: 40.9659. max: 2273

string replace: 
avg: 18.4566. max: 1478

```
string strOrg = "<ul>\n" +
                "<li>abc\n" +
                "<li>bbc\n" +
                "<li>xyz\n" +
                "<li>pqr </li></li></li></li>\n" +
                "</ul>";

string strFinal = FixUnorderedList(strOrg);

public static string FixUnorderedList(string str)
{
    //remove what we're going to put back later
    //(these could be placed on the same line, one after the other)
    str = str.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
    str = str.Replace("</li>", string.Empty);
    str = str.Replace("<ul>", string.Empty);
    str = str.Replace("</ul>", string.Empty);

    //get each li element
    string[] astrLIs = str.Split(new string[] { "<li>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    //rebuild the list correctly
    string strFinal = "<ul>";
    foreach(string strLI in astrLIs)
        strFinal += string.Format("\n<li>{0}</li>", strLI.Trim());

    strFinal += "\n</ul>";

    return strFinal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string unorderlist = "<ul><li>ONE</li><li>TWO</li><li>THREE</li></ul>";
        Regex regexul = new Regex("<ul>");

        Match m = regexul.Match(unorderlist);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            unorderlist = regexul.Replace(unorderlist, string.Empty);
            Regex regex1 = new Regex("<li>");
            unorderlist = regex1.Replace(unorderlist, ":");
            Regex regex2 = new Regex("</li>");
            unorderlist = regex2.Replace(unorderlist, "\n");

            Regex regex3 = new Regex("</ul>");
            unorderlist = regex3.Replace(unorderlist, "\n");

            Console.WriteLine(unorderlist);


        }
```